# Rails 5 Nested Resources Urls with Has-Many Through Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've created a small test app utilizing the Has-Many Through Association method but I can seem to get `link_to` to work with within my nested routes.

**error message**

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"categories", :location_id=>#<Category id: 1, name: "parties", created_at: "2017-11-01 17:40:25", updated_at: "2017-11-01 17:40:25">}, missing required keys: [:id]
```

**location.rb**

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :category
end
```

**category.rb**

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :locations
  has_many :products, through: :locations
end
```

**product.rb**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :locations
  has_many :categories, through: :locations
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :locations do
    resources :categories do
      resources :products
    end
  end
  root :to => 'locations#index'
end
```

**categories/index.html**

```
...
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
   <tr>
     <td><%= category.name %></td>
     <td><%= link_to 'Show', location_category_path(category) %></td>
     <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_location_category_path(category) %></td>
     <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', location_categories_path(category), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
   </tr>
<% end %>
...
```

**127.0.0.1:3000/rails/info/routes**

```
location_category_products_path GET /locations/:location_id/categories/:category_id/products(.:format)  
products#index

POST    /locations/:location_id/categories/:category_id/products(.:format)  
products#create

new_location_category_product_path  GET /locations/:location_id/categories/:category_id/products/new(.:format)  
products#new

edit_location_category_product_path GET /locations/:location_id/categories/:category_id/products/:id/edit(.:format) 
products#edit

location_category_product_path  GET /locations/:location_id/categories/:category_id/products/:id(.:format)  
products#show

PATCH   /locations/:location_id/categories/:category_id/products/:id(.:format)  
products#update

PUT /locations/:location_id/categories/:category_id/products/:id(.:format)  
products#update

DELETE  /locations/:location_id/categories/:category_id/products/:id(.:format)  
products#destroy

location_categories_path    GET /locations/:location_id/categories(.:format)    
categories#index

POST    /locations/:location_id/categories(.:format)    
categories#create

new_location_category_path  GET /locations/:location_id/categories/new(.:format)    
categories#new

edit_location_category_path GET /locations/:location_id/categories/:id/edit(.:format)   
categories#edit

location_category_path  GET /locations/:location_id/categories/:id(.:format)    
categories#show

PATCH   /locations/:location_id/categories/:id(.:format)    
categories#update

PUT /locations/:location_id/categories/:id(.:format)    
categories#update

DELETE  /locations/:location_id/categories/:id(.:format)    
categories#destroy

locations_path  GET /locations(.:format)    
locations#index

POST    /locations(.:format)    
locations#create

new_location_path   GET /locations/new(.:format)    
locations#new

edit_location_path  GET /locations/:id/edit(.:format)   
locations#edit

location_path   GET /locations/:id(.:format)    
locations#show

PATCH   /locations/:id(.:format)    
locations#update

PUT /locations/:id(.:format)    
locations#update

DELETE  /locations/:id(.:format)    
locations#destroy

root_path   GET /   
locations#index
```

Comment: You're almost there, just add the two ids you'll need to refer to that specific category: `<%= link_to 'Show', [location_id, category_id] %>`. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the route:

```
location_category_path  GET /locations/:location_id/categories/:id(.:format)
```

You need several things, the location id object and category id object:

```
<!-- /locations/:location_id/categories/:id -->
<%= link_to 'Show', [{location_id}, {category_id}] %>
```

Comment: I added the array as above and received the error `undefined local variable or method `location_id' ...` I then formatted the link like `<%= link_to 'Show', location_category_path(location_id: category.location.id, id: category.category_id) %>` and received error `undefined method `location' for #<Category:0x007fd1eb9ef128>`

Comment: Location_id and category_id are just placeholders here. What I’m trying to say is that you need to actually add the location Id and category id in the array. You get what I’m saying?

Answer (score 1):

```
location_category_path  GET /locations/:location_id/categories/:id(.:format)
```

As you can see here, the route: `location_category_path` required two things: `:location_id` & `:id`(the `id` of category you want to refer to).

In your case, you are only specifying one, and not the other. You also need to specify `:location_id`.

There is a shorter way as well to write this URL: `[location_id, category_id]`. Just write an array with both ids starting with `location_id`.

Answer (score -1):

Just to add to Arslan' answer.

You'll probably need to set `@location` in your controller if you don't have yet.

**app/controllers/categories_controller.rb**

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @location = # your code here
  end
end
```

**app/views/categories/index.html.erb**

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
   <tr>
     <td><%= category.name %></td>
     <td><%= link_to 'Show', location_category_path(@location.id, category.id) %></td>
     <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_location_category_path(@location.id, category.id) %></td>
     <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', location_categories_path(@location.id, category.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
   </tr>
<% end %>
```

For routes URL parameters, you can use either:

```
location_category_path(@location.id, category.id)
```

Which follows the order of your routes (which is `:location_id` then `:id`) when you do `bundle exec rake routes`, or you can also be specific like the following:

```
location_category_path(location_id: @location.id, id: category.id)
```

Comment: Your assumption is wrong, please read the question (`has_many :locations`). Therefore your solutions wouldn't work. You'd get an error actually: 
`undefined method id for <ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>`

Comment: No worries :) happy coding!